# Problema com Include no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Tenho as classes:

```
public class Estado {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Uf{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Cidade> Cidade { get; set; }
}

public class Cidade {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Nome { get; set; }
     public Estado Estado { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Algumas Propriedades
    public Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }
}

public class Fornecedor {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Algumas Propriedades
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Consigo Salvar um `Fornecedor` normalmente com o seu `Endereco`, `Cidade` e `Estado`.
Na hora de Editar não consigo acessar pegar os dados da `Cidade`e do `Estado`do `Endereco`.

Estou usando o seguinte código na Controller.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var fornecedor = _db.Fornecedores.Include("Endereco").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    if (fornecedor == null) return HttpNotFound();

    var model = new FornecedorViewModel
    {
         Fornecedor = fornecedor,
         Endereco = fornecedor.Endereco
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Tentei colocar `Include` `Cidade`, mas da erro dizendo que o `Fornecedor` não possui uma declaração para essa propriedade de navegação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use outra forma de `Include` para carregar até o último nível:

```
var fornecedor = _db.Fornecedores
    .Include(f => f.Endereco.Cidade.Estado)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Não esqueça de adicionar a dependência:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: Obrigado, não conhecia esse tipo de Include. Funcionou 100%.

Comment: @TiagoSilva Boa. Vou complementar.